# как вручную подключить стороннюю библиотеку в yii2

Tags: yii2

Установка, через композер меня принципиально не устраивает. Не понимаю, как кодеров может устраивать ситуация, когда не понятно, что и куда ставится. Меня это бесит, но то такое...

Вот куски кода с аналогичным подключением другой библиотеки. Файл extensions

```
'kartik-v/yii2-builder' =>                <---- где используется этот ключ?
array(
    'name' => 'kartik-v/yii2-builder',    <---- где используется это имя?
    'version' => '9999999-dev',
    'alias' =>
    array(
        '@kartik/builder' => $vendorDir . '/kartik-v/yii2-builder/src',          <---- где используются эти ключ и значение?
    ),
),
```

и файл autoload_psr4

```
'kartik\\builder\\' => array($vendorDir . '/kartik-v/yii2-builder/src'),         <---- где используется алиас из ключа и почему путь к папке указывается повторно, если в предыдущем файле уже было указано?
```

1. Пожалуйста, объясните каждую строчку кода.
2. Почему в двух местах указывается путь к папке?
3. Как Yii определяет какой именно файл из папки src надо брать? Есть библиотеки, у которых в папке src лежат не файлы, а подпапки. В нужной мне библиотеке https://github.com/t0k4rt/phpqrcode вообще нет папки src
4. Нужно ли в подключаемой библиотеке прописывать по файлам namespace, если оно там не прописано?
5. Что конкретно выполняет каждый из этих двух файлов?
6. Чем отличается "сторонняя библиотека" от "сторонняя библиотека для Yii"? В частности вот [это](https://github.com/t0k4rt/phpqrcode) - "сторонняя библиотека", а вот [это](https://github.com/xjflyttp/yii2-qrcode-widget) - "сторонняя библиотека для Yii2".
7. В указанных библиотеках класс QRcode и другие дублируются в разных файлах. Как однозначно указать путь к нужному файлу и соответственно классу?

Вот так

```
include(Yii::getAlias('@vendor').'/t0k4rt/phpqrcode/qrlib.php');
QRcode::png("ку-ку", 'test.png', "L", 6, 4);
```

у меня работает, но я хочу

```
use t0k4rt\phpqrcode\QRcode;
QRcode::png("ку-ку", 'test.png', "L", 6, 4);
```

Крутил-крутил, не находит класс и всё.

Буду очень признателен за подробный ответ. Если он будет ещё и на примере одной из указанных библиотек, то будет вообще супер.

Comment: Когда поймешь, что лучше потратить час, а не день, тогда станет понятно, почему есть смысл ставить пакеты через composer. Особенно это хорошо чувствуется при командной разработке. Проще же прописать пакет в composer.json и начать пользоваться библиотекой, чем пытаться вкорячить ее самому и потом на костылях решать задачу. А когда обновление выйдет, еще пару дней костылей?

Comment: не ответ, а сказка

Comment: Я не с целью как-то обидеть. Через такое, скорее всего, каждый прошел. Но рано или поздно начинаешь понимать, что composer придумали не просто так. Раньше поймешь, больше времени сэкономишь, больше сделаешь, больше опыта получишь. Раньше зарплату повысят ;)